# Error with WCF webservice moved to Azure VM

Tags: azure, wcf, iis

I have an old WCF webservice that's been moved to Azure VM.

I can easily access in Azure: 
https://wcf/service.svc, 
but when I try to post to:
https://wcf/service.svc/json/DoAction
it comes back with an empty response, when I open this in the browser I get 404 error.

Outside of Azure it all works fine, any ideas what can I do to get it to work? I would like to keep it running in VM as there are other items that were moved and work fine.

Here is the part of the web.config file that relates to "/json/" part:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  <services>
    <service name="Service123" behaviorConfiguration="ChallengeBehavior">
      <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ChallengeMessageEncoding" contract="IService123" behaviorConfiguration="SoapServiceBehavior" />
      <endpoint address="/json" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RestServiceMessageEncoding" contract="IService123" behaviorConfiguration="RestServiceBehavior" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="RestServiceBehavior">
        <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
      </behavior>
      <behavior name="SoapServiceBehavior">
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="RestServiceMessageEncoding">
        <security mode="None">
        </security>
      </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="ChallengeMessageEncoding">
        <security mode="None">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" />
          <message clientCredentialType="None" establishSecurityContext="false" negotiateServiceCredential="false" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem the code snippets seem to me. Which version IIS is installed in the Azure VM? Do you have enabled the feature supported for WCF in IIS. 
[image]
I suspect that the WCF service published on the VM does not work properly. Try to publish a default WCF service application project and browse the self-introduction page.
In addition, for a specific port, you need to enable outbound/inbound permission on the firewall.

> VM>>Settings>>Network

Feel free to contact me if there is anything I can help with.

Answer (score 0):

@Abraham, thank you for your answer.

I finally got it working, not sure which part helped but changes I introduced included:

a) Installed additional WCF features (as above) as only 2 were installed

b) Added extra bits to web config (allowing to run URLs with dots in name /Foo.svc/Save )

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  <clear />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

c) Another config to support dots:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

d) Extended endpoints to support HTTPS as the above started working for HTTP:

```
  <service name="PrivateService" behaviorConfiguration="PrivateBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="PrivateBehavior" contract="IPrivateService" behaviorConfiguration="SoapBehavior" />
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="PrivateBehaviorSecure" contract="IPrivateService" behaviorConfiguration="SoapBehavior" />
    <endpoint address="/json" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RestSecure" contract="IPrivateServices" behaviorConfiguration="RestBehavior" />
    <endpoint address="/json" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Rest" contract="IPrivateService" behaviorConfiguration="RestBehavior" />
  </service>
  ...
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="Rest">
      <security mode="None">
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="RestSecure">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
```